# Ошибка connection reset by peer при получении данных от клиента

Tags: c++, c, сокет, http

Пишу простой сервер в учебных целях. Краткий пример программы:

```
// ...
unsigned int BUFSIZE = 0;
BUFSIZE -= 2;
// ...
int clientSocket;
// Создаём подключение
// ...
char *message = new char[BUFSIZE];
while (true)
{

    long bytesNumber = 0;
    bytesNumber = recv(clientSocket, message, BUFSIZE - 1, 0);
    if (bytesNumber <= 0)
    {
        perror("recv");
        break;
    }

    // ...
    // Получаем ответ в ту же переменную message
    // ...

    bytesNumber = send(clientSocket, message, strlen(message) + 1, 0);
    if (bytesNumber < 0)
    {
        perror("send");
        break;
    }
}
delete[] message;
message = 0;
```

Когда я шлю клиенту небольшие данные - всё работает отлично. Когда же размер данных превышает 12510 байт (получил подбором), то send проходит удачно, а следующий за ним recv возвращает -1, что соответствует ошибке connection reset by peer.

Подскажите, как решить данную проблему.

**UPD**

Написал простейший клиент, который коннектится к этому серверу и общается с ним в цикле безо всяких HTTP обработок. Никаких проблем не возникло ни при приёме, ни при передаче. Возможно, я плохо знаю HTTP... Не существует ли в нём каких-либо ограничений или спец. заголовков?

**UPD**

Интересная ситуация. Проблему решил, передав в заголовке Content-length число на единицу большее реального размера данных. Странно, почему без этой единицы небольшие данные нормально передаются...

Comment: а какого размера у вас буфер? 4 гигабайта чтоли?..

Comment: @pavel я что только не пробовал. В примере да, около того. Но так-то ни с чем не работает.

Comment: Вы пишете в send  strlen(message). А message точно завершается нулем? Вообще connection reset by peer означает, что *клиент* оборвал соединение (закрыл сокет, может из-за того, что упал?)

Comment: @avp да, точно заканчивается нулём. Да и не думаю, что в этом проблема, ведь сообщения до 12510 байт передаются по тому же алгоритму и recv возвращает 0 (обычный disconnect). Насчёт падения клиента... Пробовал через curl, через браузер (http обработка добавлена) - оба варианта дают одинаковый результат. Клиент просто будто бы захлёбывается данными и падает.

Comment: Ну, вот же, *клиент просто будто бы захлёбывается данными и падает* -- поэтому и *connection reset by peer*. Проблема не в сервере.

Comment: @avp я поправил вопрос. Всё-таки была проблема с HTTP. Вопрос только, зачем ему дополнительный байт для длинных данных

Comment: @AccumPlus приведите свой код, перед вызовом `send`. Как вы записывает данные в `message`? Ошибка скорее всего в этом месте. И в протоколе HTTP конечно же существует много чего, что нужно учитывать. Только в примере кода мы никакой работы с HTTP не наблюдаем, поэтому и посоветовать что-то невозможно.

Comment: @zed проблема решена. Решение представил в ответе.

Comment: Без кода клиента разобраться не получится.

Comment: @avp да клиент - любая программа, способная посылать http-запросы. Curl как вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была глупой.

Я формирую HTTP-пакет в отдельном приложении, с которым сервер общается по трубам. После получения данных из трубы я для обеспечения некоторой безопасности добавлял в конец сообщения символ окончания строки. Понимая это, я передавал в функцию send своё сообщение, указывая длину на 1 байт больше, чем длина сообщения, полученного из трубы. И всё бы ничего, да только это увеличивает контент HTTP-сообщения на 1 байт. Таким образом, я передаю HTTP-пакет с длиной контента заведомо большей, чем это заявлено в заголовке. И, как я понял, клиент от этого действительно "захлёбывается" данными, так как ожидает, что их будет меньше.